# Get the output of a factor

Tags: r

Here is my question: I have a factor type variable composed of three levels 'NON','Oui' and 'OUI'. So when I write the variable on the console, I get these results:

> fac
>
> [1] NON
>
> Levels:  NON Oui OUI

My question is if there is a way to get the NON in front of the [1] without getting the factor levels. In other words, i want to store NON (which is the output of 'fac') in another variable without taking the levels line .

SOLVED: Thank you all. I wanted to store the output in a variable and the solution was to use as.character(fac)

Comment: try `as.character(fac)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **@jaySf** pointed out in the comments of your question, you change the vector type from `factor` to `character`:

```
as.character(fac)
```

**Additional Info:**

When you enter `fac` into the console, what you are really saying is:

```
print(fac)
```

The `print` function comes with different parameters, including the `max.levels` option

So you can specifically print `fac` without the levels by specifying:

```
print(fac, max.levels=0)
```

This will give you the output you want.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that you wanted to store the ouput into a variable. In that case, @jaySf response `as.character(fac)` does the trick!

Comment: Why don't you add that to your answer?  (I initially wrote a similar to answer to yours, then deleted it; the OP's question was easy to misread.)